# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Thickness' and 'string'

Tags: c#, wpf, types, error-handling

I am using timer for made animation and when it margins come to the value, I want should stop.
"Bir" is my shape and "ZamanSayacıA" is my timer.

```
if (Bir.Margin == "510, 410, 0, 0")
        {
            ZamanSayacıA.Stop();
        }
```

And gives the following error.

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Thickness' and 'string'

Comment: what is the type of `Bir.Margin`? It isn't a string and apparently doesn't have an implicit convert to a string

Comment: try if(Bir.Margin == new Margin(510,410,0,0))...... because you are comapring the margin with a string, which cannot be done

Comment: @GiladGreen: it's `Thickness` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare a [`Thickness`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness(v=vs.110).aspx) and a `string` with the `==` operator because both are different types. But the `Thickness` has a constructor that comes in handy:

```
Thickness th = new Thickness(510, 410, 0, 0);
if(Bir.Margin.Equals(th))
{

}
```

since the [`==` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx) is overloaded you can also use:

```
if(Bir.Margin == th)
{

}
```

---

If you only have a string `"510, 410, 0, 0"` and you need to get a `Thickness`:

```
double[] thLengths = Array.ConvertAll("510, 410, 0, 0".Split(','), double.Parse);
Thickness th = new Thickness(thLengths[0], thLengths[1], thLengths[2], thLengths[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Bir.Margin` is not a `string` but a [`Thickness`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness(v=vs.110).aspx). You cannot compare a `string` instance directly to an instance of `Thickness`.

You should create a `Thickness` to compare `Bir.Margin` to:

```
if (Bir.Margin == new Margin(510,410,0,0))
```